# Xamarin.iOS : Image resizes/Scales to blank

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**When we click image from camera to upload we scale down the image to 800*600 size but after uploading to server image is showing gray/currpeted**

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y21d.png)

We are using below code in Xamarin.iOS to Scale the image but after uploading image to server its showing gray/blank image

```
var sourceSize = sourceImage.Size;
var maxResizeFactor = Math.Min(newSize.Width / sourceSize.Width, newSize.Height / sourceSize.Height);

if (maxResizeFactor > 1) return sourceImage;
var width = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Width;
var height = maxResizeFactor * sourceSize.Height;
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new CGSize(width, height));
sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, width, height));
var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
return resultImage;
```

Comment: resize code looks ok, it should return normal UIImage, did you tried to save it locally is it looks ok? Maybe problem on server processing side.

Comment: Yes, we save it locally. It looks normal when we upload it to the server but after uploading the local image is also replaced with this blank image. This issue only happening with iOS not android

Comment: **but after uploading the local image is also replaced with this blank image** - how is that possible? upload to external server can't change local image, if it changed then it is some local code that changed it.